# How can we pass FORM data from included file to another page?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I had included footer.php in index file and the footer contains FORM for Subscriber Register.
when i click to submit a new subscriber email from https://mywebsite.com/index.php the value is not being passed from index.php page the same code is perfectly apply when i use url https://mywebsite.com/footer.php

**footer.php**

```
<form id="newsletterForm" action="newsletter-subscribe.php" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group input-group-rounded">
    <input name="mailid" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <span>
    <input type="submit">
    </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**newsletter-subscribe.php**

```
    <?php 
         if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         $email = $_POST["mailid"];
         $recipient = "info@myemail.com";
         $email_content = "
        
        <html>
        <body>
        <h2>Hello You had a new Subscriber!</h2>
            
        <h3>Email Id : ".$email." </h3>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";
        $email_headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $email_headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

        $email_headers .= 'From: info@myemail.com' . "\r\n";

        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            $msg= "Thanks You! For Subscribing our service.";
            echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'>;window.location.href='../index.php';</script>";
        } else {
            $error= "Faild To Send Your Order. Please Try Again.";  
            echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'>alert ('$error');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        }

    } else {        
        $error1= "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
        echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'>alert ('$error1');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: I see no reason why the form should not submit to `newsletter-subscribe.php`. Do you get any errors? What doesn't work? You use `'index.php'` as location.href twice, but on success you use `'../index.php'`, is that a different file?

Comment: The same thing i had applied in contactus.php and its working very well even i am having email from this code also but email id missing.

Comment: put your html code of index.php also. if it is working in other pages then some issue will be in html code of index.php

Comment: Sir, there is nothing in index file i just had include the file footer.php in it by using
<?php include 'footer.php';?>